# How can I unlock two relays at the same time with one push button?

Tags: motor, relay

I am making a circuit to control the opening and closing of a small gate with two push buttons and two limit switches. The gate open and close functionality already works, but I want to add a general emergency stop button. I can't find a way to put a normal closed push button to disengage the two relays and brake the motor, I have tried putting it in different places in the circuit without success.

This is the circuit:

[image]

Any other comments on the circuit are also appreciated.

Comment: Your NC button would need to disconnect power to all the parts of the circuit.

Comment: What are the NC buttons in circuit for?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm assuming those are the limit switches

Comment: The OP should ideally answer that question @Finbarr

Comment: The nc buttons are the limit switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something like the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6l2XB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It worked great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could connect a normally closed button between the two relay coils and ground. This would de-energize the coils and connect both motor terminals to ground, making it brake.